# Access to rds-describe-db-instances from Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS instance and am using Boto to programmatically work with that instance.

Outside of Boto, the AWS RDS api has a method to obtain status information for an RDS instance: `rds-describe-db-instances` as described [in their docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-DescribeDBInstances.html).

However, I cannot find a way to access the same method from a [Boto RDS object](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/rds.html). Is it not implemented yet, just indirectly accessible from another object type, or am I completely missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want, but this lets me get the status for a current RDS instance:

```
import boto

rds = boto.connect_rds()
instances = rds.get_all_dbinstances()
instances[0].status
```

u'available'

Perhaps you are looking for something else from the instance object?

Comment: That's absolutely what I was looking for and was making a dumb mistake...using the returned lists status rather than the status on the first object on the list: e.g. `instances.status` rather than `instances[0].status`. Thank you.